# Selenium WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: selenium

I have the following code:

```
package grid;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;


 public class TestGrid {

static Webdriver driver;
static String nodeUrl;  

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    nodeUrl = "http://192.168.100.4:5555/wd/hub";
    //DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.


}

}
```

I receive the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at grid.TestGrid.main(TestGrid.java:16)
```

I already added the 2 Jars outside the "Lib" folder, but still doesn't work. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add the selenium as an external jar in your build path:

[image: example]